# Display SKU in Woocommerce single product page with OceanWP theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sku

I want to display the SKU field of each product in its signle product page. The woocommerce plugin's settings does not have that option in wordpress.

I already followed the instructions here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219410/how-to-show-product-sku-on-product-page/219427#219427

I tried adding to my `functions.php` file this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dev_designs_show_sku', 5 );
function dev_designs_show_sku(){
    global $product;
    echo 'SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();
}
```

And also tried to add this code to the theme's single product content file:

```
if ( 'sku' === $element ) {
    woocommerce_template_single_sku();
}
```

file name is `owp-single-product.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single product template.
 *
 * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

// Get price conditional display state.
$ocean_woo_single_cond = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_woo_single_conditional', false );

// Conditional vars.
$show_woo_single = '';
$show_woo_single = ( is_user_logged_in() && $ocean_woo_single_cond === true );

/**
 * Display Single Product template
 * 
 */

// Get elements.
$elements = oceanwp_woo_summary_elements_positioning();

// Loop through elements.
foreach ( $elements as $element ) {

    do_action( 'ocean_before_single_product_' . $element );

    // Title.
    if ( 'title' === $element ) {

        woocommerce_template_single_title();

    }
    
    // Sku.
    if ( 'sku' === $element ) {

        woocommerce_template_single_sku();

    }

    // Rating.
    if ( 'rating' === $element ) {

        woocommerce_template_single_rating();

    }

    // Price.
    if ( 'price' === $element ) {

        if ( false === $ocean_woo_single_cond || $show_woo_single ) {

            woocommerce_template_single_price();

        }
    }

    // Excerpt.
    if ( 'excerpt' === $element ) {

        woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();

    }

    // Quantity & Add to cart button.
    if ( 'quantity-button' === $element ) {

        if ( false === $ocean_woo_single_cond || $show_woo_single ) {

            woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();

        } else {

            // Get Add to Cart button message display state.
            $ocean_woo_single_msg = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_woo_single_cond_msg', 'yes' );

            if ( 'yes' === $ocean_woo_single_msg ) {

                // Get Add to Cart button replacement message.
                $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_woo_single_cond_msg_text' );
                $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt = $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt ? $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt : esc_html__( 'Log in to view price and purchase', 'oceanwp' );

                $woo_single_myaccunt_link = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_single_add_myaccount_link', false );

                echo '<div class="owp-woo-single-cond-notice">';
                if ( false === $woo_single_myaccunt_link ) {
                    echo '<span>'. $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt .'</span>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '">' . $ocean_woo_single_msg_txt . '</a>';
                }   
                echo '</div>';

            }
        }
    }

    // Meta.
    if ( 'meta' === $element ) {

        woocommerce_template_single_meta();
        
    }

    do_action( 'ocean_after_single_product_' . $element );

}
```

Did not work! What do I do?

Comment: First code that you added to functions.php file looks correct. Did you get any error?

Comment: @OzgurSar no errors

Comment: Can you share your code of single product php file of your theme?

Comment: @OzgurSar please see edit

Comment: Try enabling error reporting and see if you see an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to show the sku after product title

```
add_action( 'ocean_after_single_product_title', 'show_product_sku', 5 );
function show_product_sku(){
    global $product;
    echo 'SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this? I added it to `functions.php` instead of the previous code and still does not working.

Comment: Yes, normally you should add it to your child theme's functions.php file. Alternatively (if you don't have child theme) you can install Code Snippets plugin and add this code as a snippet. https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: I don't use a child theme but I added it to `functions.php` file of the theme

Comment: It is not a best practice because your code will be overwritten when the theme is updated.

Comment: I installed Ocean's child theme and added this code to the `functions.php` file and still not working. I deleted the code I added to the single product file, do I need to put back that code? or just this code should be fine?

Comment: The code in my answer is meant to be added to Child or Main theme's `functions.php` or to be added via Code Snippets plugin. Please do not add it into single product file.

Comment: I did not added it to single product file. I added it to the `functions.php` file of the child's theme. I asked if I need to add something to the signle product file as well? or this code should be fine? because its not working.

Comment: Yes, this should be enough. No other code needs to be added to the single product file. You can try the code with another theme (such as WP default Twenty Twenty)

Comment: I can't change the theme. What else can i do?